# What is the fastest option for printing a single page report (wpf c# program)

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, rdl

I am devoloping a wpf c# program that manages a school. From time to time the user has to print certifications for a single student. For instance a certification that this student is learning in our institution, or a certification with the amount of his stipend.

On these reports there is:

1. fixed text
2. dynamic information about the student like his name and so on

For this task I built rdls and it serves the purpose, but the users requested faster speed.

My question is: are rdls (working off a report server) the right method for this task? or is there a different faster option?

Answer (score 1):

I use a `FlowDocument` for simple printing functionality such as this. You add XAML elements to the document just as you would when programmatically creating XAML in a window. Use the same layout controls (grids, stack panels, etc) to arrange all the other controls (text paragraphs, images, etc), and when the FlowDocument is printed it will be "flowed" into the page(s) based on various factors such as the paper size selected in the printer dialog.

Disclaimer: this was copy/pasted in a rush but it should give you an idea of how it works!

```
// Show the print dialog
var dlg = new PrintDialog();
if (!dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
    // User cancelled
    return;
}

// Create and initialise the FlowDocument
_doc = new FlowDocument();
_doc.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
_doc.FontSize = 14;

// Add a paragraph of text
var para = new Paragraph(new Run("My paragraph....."))
{
    FontSize = 14,
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,12)
};
_doc.Blocks.Add(para);

// Add an image
var para = new Paragraph();
var img = new Image
{
    Source = bitmapSource, 
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, 
    Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,12)
};
para.Inlines.Add(img);
_doc.Blocks.Add(para);

// Print
var documentPaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)_doc).DocumentPaginator;
dlg.PrintDocument(documentPaginator, "My print job");
```

In my application I have all this wrapped in a class (as I have a few places where I need printing functionality). The class creates and initialises the FlowDocument in its constructor, and provides various methods such as "AddParagraph()", "AddImage()", with different overloads for specifying margins, fonts, font sizes, etc.

The document paginator bit at the end is a simplified version of my implementation, but it may be sufficient for your needs. (I've created a custom document paginator that provides the ability to set a header and footer on each page).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am starting with this method, trying to build a printed paper. I am sure i will have to check this method to find out if it will allow instant printing without previewing, export to html or docx, and so on.